# OpenEdge 10.2A - Error Screen With No Other Info, how to solve it?

Tags: runtime-error, openedge

We are using Progress OpenEdge 10.2A for years and for the last 4 months we begin to receive unknown error messages from our customers.

We call our .w files using lines as follows:

`RUN VALUE(myPath + "myProgram.r") PERSISTENT SET myPrograms[i].`

Normally the same program calls work without any problem, but on rare occasions, the program window seems to get unresponsive, but in fact when we look at the windows taskbar, there is another entry in the taskbar which is a prowin32.exe window having title "Error". But when selected, there seems to have no visible window attached to it.

When we close it from the taskbar using Close Window option, it appears again in the taskbar 6-7 times again and then whole prowin32 session restarts.

We could not identify the error since it does not show any message or any error number.

If you encounter such a problem, I'd like to know how you solved it.

If not, it would be appreciated if you direct me to the way to solve the problem.

[image: Taskbar]

[image: Task Manager]

**Edit 1:**
After adding **-errorstack -debugalert -clientlog myLogFile.log** to my startup parameters, myLogFile.log is generated. The below part is written when the error occured.

```
**Unable to realise TEXT myText. (4025)
** ABL Debug-Alert Stack Trace **
--> enable_UI c:\myFolder\myFile1.r (c:\myFolder\myFile1.r) at line 21014
    c:\myFolder\myFile1.r (c:\myFolder\myFile1.r) at line 14858
    USER-INTERFACE-TRIGGER c:\myFolder\myFile2.r (c:\myFolder\myFile2.r) at line 2905
```

Comment: Are there any protrace or procore files in the working directory of the application on the user machines?

Comment: The strange thing is; in the client pc having this error today, there is no protrace file created today. The closest date for the protrace file is from one week ago and the computer is restarted every day. I have informed the user and he will contact me immediately when he sees the error again. I'll look for protrace and procore files again. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The attached images are unreadably tiny.

Comment: They are original sized images. One image is from task manager and the other one from taskbar. When Error screen is selected nothing is shown so it is the best images I can get.

Answer (score 1):

0) OpenEdge 10.2a is ancient, obsolete and unsupported. You should have moved to a modern release 10 years ago.  At the very minimum you should be on 10.2b08. Do you also refuse to update Windows? OpenEdge 12 is the current release. It is possible, perhaps even likely, that unanticipated changes in Windows or other aspects of the environment are causing your problem.  Progress is never going to update 10.2a to accommodate that sort of thing. You are just prolonging the agony by staying on an obsolete release.

1) What changed in your code or your environment 4 months ago?

2) You can get a stack trace for the extra prowin32 session by running proGetStack.  That should help to explain what was launched, what the error is and why another 6-7 start after you kill it.  Open a "proenv" window as "Administrator" and run proGetStack  (you can get the process id from taskmgr).

```
proenv>  proGetStack 123456
```

The stack trace will appear in the working directory of the target process.  That is usually the same directory that proenv is in but it is possible that the application changes it so you might have to go hunting for it.  (Administrator proenv windows sometimes do not start in %wrkdir%, you may also need to cd /d %wrkdir%)

3) If they are not already present you should add -debugalert and -errorstack to your client startup parameters.  -clientlog logfileName.log would probably also be helpful.

4) Examine your code base for bits that invoke prowin32 sub-processes.  There are many ways to do this such as OS-COMMAND, INPUT THROUGH or via Windows DLL calls.  Directly invoking prowin32 can be found by searching for that string but it might also be indirect invocations via a BAT file or other technique.

5) if you have a repeatable way to produce the error then you could also add the 4GLTrace log entry type either at startup or in the code when you get to the proper point: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dpspr/log-entry-types-(-logentrytypes).html

Comment: 0: We have more than 5000 clients and it is not up to me to decide a version upgrade. 1: There are more than 1000 .w files and we are constantly adding/changing codes and it is very hard for me to investigate each change. But I have checked a few programs, in which the error occurs most, and compared them to the versions of one year ago, and I could not find any major change in them. 2-3: I have started proGetStack and used -errorstack -debugalert -clientlog myLogFile.log and waiting for the log files.

Comment: 4: There was a .net library include (USING System.Text.RegularExpressions.*.) in some of our programs. I have cancelled them but the error persists. There is no OS-COMMAND, DOS, INPUT THROUGH, DLL calls etc. where the error emerges. We have a main window having menus etc. The error occurs when the user runs a new .w file by selecting from main menu or by openning it through another sub program.

Comment: Whether it is up to you or not is not material to whether or not it is a problem.

Comment: "The error occurs when..." if you have a repeatable way to produce the error then you could also add the 4gltrace log entry type either at startup or in the code when you get to the proper point: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dpspr/log-entry-types-(-logentrytypes).html

Comment: Unfortunately, the error occurs rarely, we do not have a repeatable pattern. There are more than 5000 users, but only 10 users in 3 different locations get the error. And those users do not get the error all the time, maybe one in a thousand runs. Let me clarify my point; if the error occurs, we observed that it occurs just after openning of a sub program using main program menu option or trough another sub program and just before showing the content of the opened sub program. [My English might be insufficient, sorry for that]

Comment: When we look at the myLogFile.log, it seems the error message is **Unable to realise TEXT myText. (4025).